# Make cross domain request for JSON with new Fetch API

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cors, fetch-api

I'm having CORS issues with fetch and have exhausted google. In the codepen below, I'm trying to hit flickr's open api for some images. You'll see two buttons. "Search with jquery" works fine, using $.getJSON.

Of course, I'd like to use Fetch. "Search with Fetch" doesn't work. When I try to send the same request, I get this error:

```
Fetch API cannot load http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=dog&tagmode=any. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
console_runner-ba402f0a8d1d2ce5a72889b81a71a979.js:1 TypeError: Failed to fetch(…)
```

When I add `mode: 'no-cors'`, then all I get back is an `opaque` response that doesn't contain any data.

Try for yourself! http://codepen.io/morgs32/pen/OMGEpm?editors=0110

Would love a hand. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can see, the problem appears to be just the Flickr isn’t sending any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header at all in its response for your request for http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=dog&tagmode=any. As the error message you pasted in says, `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the Flickr API is using [JSONP](http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/).

If you run `curl 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=asd&tagmode=any&format=json' -H 'Host: api.flickr.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0' -H 'Accept: */*'` in your console, you don't get a JSON response:

```
jsonFlickrFeed({
    "title": "Recent Uploads tagged asd",
    "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/asd/",
    "description": "",
    "modified": "2016-02-16T18:34:00Z",
    "generator": "http://www.flickr.com/",
    "items": [
   {
     ...
})
```

`JSONP` is automatically supported by `getJSON`, but not by `fetch`.